# How to use multiple models in one app?

Tags: django, models

I have a django project with two applications, `experiments` and `metadata` and in one view I need to work with models from both these applications, so I have this:

```
from experiments.models import *
from metadata.models import *
```

Both my applications have a model with the same name; so how can I use two models in one app?

Answer (score 3):

```
from experiments import models as exp_models
from metadata import models as meta_models

foo = exp_models.Foo.objects.all()
bar = meta_models.Bar.objects.all()
```

Btw. `from module import *` is considered as bad practice, it clutters your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose in `experiments/models.py` you have:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And in `metadata/models.py` you also have:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now you want to use both, you would import them like this:

```
from metadata.models import Foo as meta_foo
from experiments.models import Foo as experiment_foo
```